# How do I make a post / get request to a endpoint with a requestHeader?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

Method in question

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getSomeData(@RequestHeader String someId) {
  ...some code
}
```

Tried to call the consume the endpoint with this method:

```
@Autowired
WebClient.Builder webClient;
String someString = webClient.
  .get()
  .uri(someUrl)
  .header("someId", "someString")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .block();
```

I got a status 415 with Unsupported media type with "Content type '' not supported"

How do I use webClientBuilder to set my id header?

Comment: Can you post the full configuration of your WebClient? You are autowiring the builder here. There's some incomplete information here.

Comment: Webclient full configuration? I'm using spring boot here. I'm under assumption that it is auto configured for me when I inject it here. @Alexander Katsenelenbogen

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the correct content-type. If your controller expects it to be "plain/text" you might have to set that explicitly within your requesting client. 415 does indicate a miss match.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Alex you are autowiring builder instead look for the concrete implementation of WebClient. Please check my WebClient config bean. But that is not the actual issue.

When you are sending body with webClient you have to use

```java
.body(...)
```

so for sending plain text body where controller is expecting plain body you need something like below:

```java
.body(BodyInserters.fromProducer(Mono.just("random body"), String.class))
```

and when controller is expecing an object is request you need to use something like this

```java
 .body(BodyInserters.fromProducer(Mono.just(new Greet("Hello there this is the body of post request")), Greet.class))
```

Greet.java

```java
public static class Greet {
        String name;

        public Greet() {
        }

        public Greet(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Configuration of WebCLient

```java
@Configuration
    class WebClientConfig {
        @Bean
        WebClient webClient() {
            return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/").build();
        }
    }
```

```java
@RequestMapping("/sample")
    @RestController
    static class SampleComntroller {

        private final WebClient webClient;

        @Autowired
        SampleComntroller(WebClient webClient) {
            this.webClient = webClient;
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/main-get")//, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public Mono<String> helloGet(@RequestHeader(name = "someId") String someId) {
            return Mono.just("Hello, Spring!, get, response with header is=>" + someId);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/main-post-plain-string", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
        public Mono<String> helloPost(@RequestHeader(name = "someId") String someId, @RequestBody String body) {
            return Mono.just("Hello, Spring!, post, response with header is=>" + someId + " and random body " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/main-post-object", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public Mono<String> helloPostObject(@RequestHeader(name = "someId") String someId, @RequestBody Greet greet) {
            return Mono.just("Hello, Spring!, post, response with header is=>" + someId + " " + greet.getName() + " " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        @GetMapping("/delegate-get")
        public String delegateGet() {
            return webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri("/sample/main-get")
                    .header("someId", "178A-0E88-get")
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        }

        @PostMapping("/delegate-post")
        public String delegatePost() {
            return webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("/sample/main-post-plain-string")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromProducer(Mono.just("random body"), String.class))
                    .header("someId", "178A-0E88-post")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        }

        @PostMapping("/delegate-post-object")
        public String delegatePostObject() {
            return webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("/sample/main-post-object")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromProducer(Mono.just(new Greet("Hello there this is the body of post request")), Greet.class))
                    .header("someId", "178A-0E88-post")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where can I find your webclient config bean?

Comment: It is there in my answer please check.